# Why codepen example with alpinejs does not work anymore?

Tags: alpine.js

I wanted to post an alpinejs question with codepen example,
but opening my old codepen I found it was not working.
I replaced reference to 2.1 version with 3.x branch line:

```
  <script src="//unpkg.com/alpinejs" defer></script>
```

But in the browser's console I have several errors as result my priorly working example does not work now.
Please check saved pen : https://codepen.io/petrogromovo/pen/yLMNVLr

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I open your codepen example, everything works fine. I get the "appInit::" log in console, and the `showModal` variable is updated properly when the "open modal" button is clicked. (Showed it on screen the same way you posted the `isPageLoaded` variable)

Your modal doesn't show, however, because you have a class "hidden" on the modal. AlpineJS doesn't set the style of the display to something like "block". It just removes the `display: none;`, and because you have class "hidden" applied, the modal will forever be hidden.

Comment: Thanks! Do you see errors in the console,  like https://imgur.com/a/wVqS2xB ?

Comment: @PetroGromovo I do see errors like yours when I run it on FF, but they don't impact the code. When run from Chrome, all I get is `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'this'`, but still, code runs fine. I see you've updated the modal class!